# Carpal Tunnel and Trigger fingers surgery

Tags: united-states, health, disability, leave-of-absence

A month ago I received two surgeries done on my hands for carpal tunnel and trigger fingers. My short turn disability has ended, and I'm still sore. My Dr. wrote a note to HR for light work.

My Dr. sends all medical notes to HR, and HR has not answered me back telling me to come back to work. I have been calling for days and leaving messages to please call me back.

I need to go back to work and HR is not responding,  I also call the HR assistant and leave the same messages but no one responds.

I should have  been at work 3 days ago, my short turn disability has run out , and I have to pay bills.

Should the company pay me for those days? They don't answer my calls so its their fault I'm not back to work.

Please let me know what else I should do.

Comment: What about your immediate supervisor? Can you call him/her and explain the situation and perhaps that person could speak to HR and get the ball rolling?

Answer (score 9):

> I should have been at work 3 days ago, my short turn disability has
>   run out , and I have to pay bills.
>
> Should the company pay me for those days? They don't answer my calls
>   so its their fault I'm not back to work.
>
> Please let me know what else I should do.

If your short-term disability has run out and you are able to work, you should show up at your workplace and talk directly with HR.

Bring your paperwork from your doctor indicating that you need light work.

It's not clear if you'll be paid for the three days, since disability is an insurance issue. Discuss that with HR.

Comment: Thanks you guys for all your help..  I did attempt to approach to HR, its come back with their answer.  Metrix the company insurance are working with my Dr.  
 I said I have Dr. Papers here if you give me sometimes I will pass by and bring it to you... No HR said the company insurance is taking charge of your Dr. Paper. 
So I think I have to wait till next week after the holidays to hear any respond from HR.